# SQL Efficiency - Multiple Attribute Filtering, best practice on ecommerce solution

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have an existing MSSQL database for an ecommerce solution.  There are many product attribute groups, and many attributes.  The client requires a filtering solution and I feel that the current implementation is not very efficient, so I wanted to reach out to the DBA community to field some suggestions on how to best go about improving.

The Data Structure (Simple many-to-many relationship):

```
ProductAttribute Table
------
ProductId 
AttributeId 

Attribute Table
-------
AttributeId
AttributeGroupId

AttributeGroup Table
-------
AttributeGroupId
```

The main problem here is that on the client side, they can select as many filters as they want.  However, for each attribute in the group, it's kind of an "or" selection, while attributes in other groups are "and" selections.

Example:
AttributeGroup Color: Red, Green
AttributeGroup Length: Long
AttributeGroup Material: Silk, Linen

So basically I need to return any products that match Red/Long/Silk, Red/Long/Linen, Green/Long/Silk, Green/Long/Linen.

Right now the stored procs examines each of these groups individually in a Soviet style, super long proc that gets the job done.  First building a temp table of productIds that match the first group (Color), then removing the Ids that don't match the successive AttributeGroup filters.  Example: Give me all the red and green products.  Then remove any products that aren't also "Long".  Now remove any remaining products that aren't also Linen or Silk.

The proc works fairly well, but now that this site's busy season is upon us, it doesn't seem to scale very well and I'm looking to improve its efficiency.  There can be up to 12 different Groups, and many different attributes within each group.

The data can be passed in any way, but is currently a multi-delimited string which is parsed into a table using an sql function.  AttributeGroupId-AttributeId,AttributeId|AttributeGroupId-AttributeId,AttributeId
Example: 1-104,114|2-125,140|3-215,317

EDIT: Example of how the input data is parsed

```
AttributeGroupId| Attribute Id
------------------------------
1               | 104
1               | 114
2               | 125
2               | 140
3               | 215
3               | 317
```

Without going deep into the current proc, any recommendations on how best to tackle this problem?

Comment: With no details about implementation how could anybody offer any help to improve the performance?

Comment: If the AttributeId is unique then the AttributeGroupID is pointless in the search routine. It sounds like you just need a list of AttributeId's since that is what is bound to to the product. "Give me all products joined on this list of attributes."

Comment: I'd like to redesign it, so how its currently implemented shouldn't really matter.

Comment: The group is important because we're not looking for products that match all of the attributes.  it can be Red OR Green, but it also has to have the length of long, and either Linen or Silk in the example.  So if you we just joined on the list of attributes it would return only products that match ALL of the submitted criteria -- products that are red and green and long and linen and silk, where a product that is only red, long, and silk should be valid, even if it doesnt come in green or linen.

Comment: OK. So even redesigning it we need a little bit of detail here. You are asking how we can help you write a query but we don't know what the table structures are (well we have a vague description), we have no idea what is in these tables or how you want to retrieve the data. We don't know how you are passing in parameters, we don't know what you want for output or the logic to get there. Help us help you by providing some details.

Comment: I specified above about a multiple delimited string  AttributeGroupId-AttributeId,AttributeId|AttributeGroupId-AttributeId,AttributeId.  I'd like to be as helpful as possible, but there's really no more to add in terms of table structure (its just Name, displayOrder, active, etc).  The output is a list of product ids that have a at least one of each row in the productattribute table for each attribute group passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of attributes you have, you may be able to use a [junk dimension](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/06/design-tip-113-creating-using-and-maintaining-junk-dimensions/) strategy.  There would be duplicates within a single column, but the combination of all columns would be unique.  In other words, you'd have multiple records for the color Red, but you'd only have a single Red/Long/Silk.

The number of records is the number of unique combinations across all columns.
All of the filters would be against this same table, with a single join to the ProductAttribute table.  In your example, you could make each group a column such as color.  Within a single column they can use a multi-value list to "OR" select.  Across columns would be the "AND" select.

```
Select AttributesID, Color, Length, Material From Attributes
Where Color in (@Color) and Length in (@Length) AND Material in (@Material)
```

Comment: Thanks, Wes: I'll take a look into the Junk Dimension.  The current proc uses the second style approach, which requires maintenance every time a new attribute group gets added.  It is also an unwieldy 500+ line procedure of duplicated code which I'm trying to refactor and whittle down.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the second style.

This approach would requirement maintenance every time a new attribute group gets added, but not when adding a new attribute to a group.  How often do you add new groups?

Comment: It gets updated often enough to try to get around that.  What I'm struggling with in regards to the junk dimensions, is how to then associate a combination with a product that matches.

Comment: Each combination gets a unique identifier in the junk dimension.  Your product table references the unique identifier for the junk dimension.

You'll be hard pressed to find a solution that doesn't require maintenance to add a new group if you are using a separate parameters for each group.

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure you can bind your filter logic in a **heavy** where statement that matches each group's attributes with ORs and then ANDs other groups.

NOTE : A query like this will most likely **send the query optimizer into orbit** and horrible things will happen. If you do implement something similar you need to set the `WITH RECOMPILE` option or test with `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`

Basically, in the where clause, you want to exclude each item not in the group, or it is in the group and there exists a filter and the filter matches.

```
DECLARE @Attributes TABLE(AttributeGroupID INT,AttributeID INT)
INSERT @Attributes SELECT 1,104--COLOR
INSERT @Attributes SELECT 1,114--COLOR
INSERT @Attributes SELECT 2,125--LENGTH
INSERT @Attributes SELECT 2,140--LENGTH
INSERT @Attributes SELECT 3,215--MATERIAL
INSERT @Attributes SELECT 3,317--MATERIAL

DECLARE @AttributeGroup TABLE(AttributeGroupID INT)
INSERT @AttributeGroup SELECT 1--COLOR
INSERT @AttributeGroup SELECT 2--LENGTH
INSERT @AttributeGroup SELECT 3--MATERIAL

DECLARE @Product TABLE(ProductID INT)
INSERT @Product SELECT 1 
INSERT @Product SELECT 2


DECLARE @ProductAttribute TABLE(ProductID INT,AttributeID INT)
INSERT @ProductAttribute SELECT 1,104
INSERT @ProductAttribute SELECT 1,125
INSERT @ProductAttribute SELECT 1,317
INSERT @ProductAttribute SELECT 2,114
INSERT @ProductAttribute SELECT 2,125
INSERT @ProductAttribute SELECT 2,215


DECLARE @Filter TABLE(AttributeGroupID INT,AttributeID INT)
INSERT @Filter SELECT 1,104
INSERT @Filter SELECT 2,125
--INSERT @Filter SELECT 3,317

SELECT
    P.ProductID,
    MatchingAttrinuteCount=COUNT(*)
FROM
    @Product P
    INNER JOIN @ProductAttribute PA ON PA.ProductID=P.ProductID
    INNER JOIN @Attributes A ON A.AttributeID=PA.AttributeID
WHERE
    (A.AttributeGroupID<>1 OR(A.AttributeGroupID=1 AND ( (NOT(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Filter WHERE AttributeGroupID=1))) OR PA.AttributeID IN(SELECT F.AttributeID FROM @Filter F WHERE F.AttributeGroupID=1))))
    AND
    (A.AttributeGroupID<>2 OR(A.AttributeGroupID=2 AND ( (NOT(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Filter WHERE AttributeGroupID=2))) OR PA.AttributeID IN(SELECT F.AttributeID FROM @Filter F WHERE F.AttributeGroupID=2))))
    AND
    (A.AttributeGroupID<>3 OR(A.AttributeGroupID=3 AND ( (NOT(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Filter WHERE AttributeGroupID=3))) OR PA.AttributeID IN(SELECT F.AttributeID FROM @Filter F WHERE F.AttributeGroupID=3))))
GROUP BY
    P.ProductID
```

The query above will yield :

```
ProductID   MatchingAttrinuteCount
1           3
2           2
```

**A second and possibly more performant method...**

It is generally a good idea to shy away from cursors, however, this is one of the times that cursors prove useful. Note : You will be loading all products that meet the first criteria encountered into memory as your largest set. If you don't think this value will be HUGE then the cursor logic below should prove more compact and efficient.

```
DECLARE @Filter TABLE(AttributeGroupID INT,AttributeID INT)
INSERT @Filter SELECT 1,104
INSERT @Filter SELECT 2,125
INSERT @Filter SELECT 1,114
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Matches TABLE(ProductID INT,AttributeID INT)
DECLARE @AttributeID INT, @AttributeGroupID INT, @HasLooped BIT=0
--GROUPS TO LOOP FOR 
DECLARE ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT AttributeGroupID FROM @Filter
OPEN ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CURSOR INTO @AttributeGroupID

--FOR EACH GROUP [COLOR..MATERIAL] IN THE FILTER 
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)BEGIN

    INSERT @Matches 
    --INSERT ALL PRODUCTS WITH MATCHING ATTRIBUTES IN THIS GROUP
    --IF FIRST LOOP EXAMINE ALL PRODUCTS IF NOT EXAMINE ONLY PRODUCTS ALREADY IN MATCH SET
    SELECT P.ProductID, PA.AttributeID 
    FROM @Product P
    INNER JOIN @ProductAttribute PA ON PA.ProductID=P.ProductID 
    WHERE 
        AttributeID IN (SELECT AttributeID FROM @Filter F WHERE F.AttributeGroupID=@AttributeGroupID ) 
        AND 
        (@HasLooped=0 OR P.ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM @Matches)) --Only match products if one filter has been applied

    SET @HasLooped=1

    FETCH NEXT FROM ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CURSOR INTO @AttributeGroupID

END

CLOSE ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CURSOR

SELECT * FROM @Matches
```

Yielding...

```
ProductID   AttributeID
1           104
2           114
1           125
2           125
```

Comment: Cursors are never a good idea for set based data retrieval.  This is effectively running the query for every combination selected by the user.  There are so many other ways to do this, a cursor should not even be considered.

Comment: The cursor method was about 500ms slower than the existing proc.  300ms vs 800ms.  Although the code was much more concise. =\

Comment: citizenkraft - you are going to need either N joins or N subqueries into a filterset. The Where clause above uses the former. Wes H is correct on cursor usage. It should be avoided as it bypasses optimizations that set based operations can take advantage of, however, if your product table consists of thousands of records, not HUGE, the performance loss may be negligible. It's for you to test. You did not state how big the tables are. I would be interested to know how the where clause solution worked.